# How to write the below SQL query to LINQ query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, select, linq-to-entities, inner-join

How to convert normal SQL to LINQ query? Is there tools that can do that?? Online Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this (a few joins omitted for brevity):

```
var result = from s in TooltipsLanguage
                              join c in TooltipsLanguageSection on s.Id equals c.IdLanguage
                              join p in TooltipsSection on c.IdSection equals p.Id
                              join ...
                              select new MyDestinationObject()
                              {
                                  Id = s.BusinessEntityID,
                                  Language = s.Language,
                                  IdLanguage = c.IdLanguage,
                                  ...
                              };
```

Comment: TooltipsLanguageSection
TooltipsSection
TooltipsItem
TooltipsText

all of those lines are showing errors saying that "...is a Type, which is not valid in given context"

and also MyDestinationObject() cound not be found....

Comment: Anymore tips, please...

Comment: MyDestinationObject is a made up object... you would need to instantiate an object type that actually exists.  Do you have like a ToolTipResult object or something?

Comment: This also presumes you've created the LINQ to SQL classes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384470.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This meight be help you.

```
var temp= edbContext.TooltipsLanguage.select(
c=> new {
TooltipsLanguage.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.Language,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.IdLanguage,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.IdSection,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section, 
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.IdItem,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.TooltipsItemText.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.TooltipsItemText.IdItem,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.TooltipsItemText.IdText,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.TooltipsItemText.TooltipsText.Id,
TooltipsLanguage.TooltipsLanguageSection.TooltipsSection.Section.TooltipsItem.TooltipsItemText.TooltipsText.Texts});
```